# Object went missing when I press space (play animation)

Tags: animation

There was little desk under those candles, and everytime I press play it dissapear. Same is with every object I copy, it just deletes. I tried unhidding everything but it doesn't appear. On the other hand, if I make new mesh, for example cube and play it doesn't delete. Also if I move something to other location and press play, it returns to the last location.
[image]

Comment: check that you are editing and adding things at frame 1. are you using auto keying or adding keyframes manually?

Comment: There is answer already, something about that keyframes. Not sure what acctualy, still learning, but thanks for help!